# Cannot access menu on HP monitor, error "OSD Lockout"

Tags: display

Whenever I press any of the buttons on my HP LP2475w monitor, the error message "OSD Lockout" is displayed. How can I get access to the settings menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unlock, keep the menu button pressed for approx. 10 seconds, until the menu is displayed.

(Some people on the Internet have reported stuck buttons, and have had to open the monitor and cut wires to resolve this problem.)